# Representing node numbers with elements from an array in Networkx

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have an array `P1`. I want to represent each node with elements of `P1`. I present the current and expected output.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

P1 = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120])

N = 2

def pos():
    x, y = 1, N + 3 - 1
    for _ in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
        yield (x, y)
        y -= (x + 2) // (N + 3)
        x = (x + 2) % (N + 3)

G = nx.Graph()
it_pos = pos()
for u in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
    G.add_node(u + 1, pos=next(it_pos))
    if u % (2 * N + 1) < N:
        for v in (u - 2 * N - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            if G.has_node(v + 1):
                G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) == N:
        G.add_edge(u + 1, u - N + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) < 2 * N:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    else:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)

nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your last line of code with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create an axis so we can work with matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')

# Draw current plot
nx.draw(G, pos, ax=ax, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

# Get positions of nodes to plot labels at
pos2 = np.array(list(pos.values())).astype(float)

# Move positions and add annotations
pos2[:, 1] += 0.3
for i, txt in enumerate(P1):
    ax.annotate(str(txt), (pos2[i, 0], pos2[i, 1]))
plt.show()
```

Plotting in this way allows you to combine matplotlib functionality with any networkx plot. Once you have done so, you can follow the link bellow to further customize your annotations:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-text-annotations-py

Results:
[image]